# How to make this repeating code more efficient: jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
    jQuery('.checkbox1').click(function(){
        jQuery(this).parent().toggleClass('active')
    });
    jQuery('.checkbox2').click(function(){
        jQuery(this).parent().toggleClass('active')
    });
    jQuery('.checkbox3').click(function(){
        jQuery(this).parent().toggleClass('active')
    });
    jQuery('.checkbox4').click(function(){
        jQuery(this).parent().toggleClass('active')
    });
```

I run the same function on all 4 of them. Can i use something like `.each()`? Can someone show me how to condense this code?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way could be to add an additional class checkbox to all the elements then use

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox checkbox1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox checkbox2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox checkbox3" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox checkbox4" />
```

then

```
jQuery('.checkbox').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).parent().toggleClass('active')
});
```

if you can't do that then use multiple selector

```
jQuery('.checkbox1, .checkbox2, .checkbox2, .checkbox4').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).parent().toggleClass('active')
});
```

Comment: +1 looks like we independently came to identical solutions. Not sure why this was downvoted.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply do this:

```
jQuery('.checkbox1, .checkbox2, .checkbox3, .checkbox4').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).parent().toggleClass('active')
});
```

Or you could create a new class, say `checkbox` to apply to all of your  checkboxes, then use this:

```
jQuery('.checkbox').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).parent().toggleClass('active')
});
```